# Memory comparison of Scala's Array[Int] v/s int[] in Java?

Tags: java, scala, jvm

Do they take the same amount of memory? Array is an abstract class so does it incur any object header cost? Is it same for other arrays of Java primitives in Scala?

PS: I read somewhere that Scala stores them as primitive arrays in JVM but now am confused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scala's Array[T] is exactly represented as Java's T[], there's no overhead. They generate the same bytecode. You additionally have the operations provided by ArrayOps, but it is an implicit conversion, which does not affect the pure Array[T] representation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not concerned about potential difference in several bytes (Scala `Array` vs Java `array` headers), they are roughly the same in terms of memory use, since Scala `Int` is represented as Java primitive `int`:

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Int

Comment: I agree scala.Int is equivalent to "int" but the question is about memory overhead of class header. @ponythewhite seems to suggest even that is not present.